# Derived mode from CC Mode: how do I write one?

Tags: cc-mode, derived-mode

Where is the definitive, up-to-date guide on how to write a derived mode from CC Mode.  I have a mode that's malfunctioning and thought I might just rewrite it, but information I find is spotty and inconsistent.  The example mode reference in the code is

http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/derived-mode-ex.el

and it doesn't look much like the mode I want to rewrite.  I wonder if maybe things have changed since this example was written in 2002.

Comment: Could you give some details about the mode you'd like to rewrite and its shortcomings?

Comment: The mode I'm thinking about rewriting is scad-mode.  The most obvious shortcoming is that it hangs when you type "#a=(".  I opened another question about that and people complained that I couldn't ask how to fix the mode and also how to write a new one.